# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method addAttributeToSelect()

Tags: magento2, customer

After deleted custom attribute and getting

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Source::addAttributeToSelect() in
>   /vendor/magento/framework/Indexer/Handler/AttributeHandler.php on line
>   38

Is this bug in Magento 2.2.3? (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10838)

Comment: yes, we have also made changes which given in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10838

Comment: Did you reindex and flush the cache?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is incredible because It is the result of a fake configuration of the file:

module-customer/etc/indexer.xml

In fact the bug is the line 14:

```
<fieldset name="customer" source="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Source"
```

must be changed in

```
<fieldset name="customer" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection"
```

So the problem is solved.